# How to initialize an object's reference member properly so that its value remains after the object constructor exits?

Tags: c++, reference

In the code below after using the `bar` initializer the value set is not the value that is stored after the `Foo` constructor ends.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int a = 2;

class Bar
{
public:
  int getLength(void);
  Bar(const int &len);  // simple constructor
  Bar(const Bar &obj);  // copy constructor
  ~Bar();               // destructor

private:
  int *ptr;
};
void display(Bar obj);
class Foo
{
public:
  const Bar &bar;

  Foo() : bar(a)
  {
  };
};

Bar::Bar(const int &len)
{
  cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;
  ptr = new int;
  *ptr = len;
}
Bar::Bar(const Bar &obj)
{
  cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
  ptr = new int;
  *ptr = *obj.ptr;  // copy the value
}

Bar::~Bar(void)
{
  cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
  delete ptr;
}
int Bar::getLength(void)
{
  return *ptr;
}
void display(Bar obj)
{
  cout << "Length of bar : " << obj.getLength() << endl;
}
int main()
{
  Bar bar(10);
  Foo foo;
  display(foo.bar);
  return 0;
}
```

How can one still use a reference variable `bar` and get around this issue?

**Actual output**

```
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Freeing memory!
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of bar : 16407632
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
```

**Required output**

```
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Freeing memory!
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of bar : 2
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
```

Comment: Does `bar` have to be kept as a reference?

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, I'm trying to avoid duplicating data. This is a reproduced bug the original class ```Bar``` is a much bigger class.

Comment: That is going to be a problem then.  `bar(a)` cause a temporary to be created.  You cannot extend the lifetime of a temporary with a reference if it is a class member variable.  there really are no good solutions to this.